# Synchronized methods - how does this work?

Tags: java, thread-safety, synchronized

I recently saw one example below. I am not able to understand how does the main and passenger thread can remain in synchronized block at once?

```
public class bus 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        passenger p = new passenger();
        p.start();
        synchronized (p) 
        {
            System.out.println("passenger is waiting for the bus, i am in synchronised method");
            p.wait();
            System.out.println("passenger  got notification");
        }
        System.out.println("after "+p.total+" time");
    }
}

class passenger  extends Thread 
{
    int total = 0;

    public void run() 
    {
        synchronized (this) 
        { 
            System.out.println("wait ....  i am in synchronised method");
            for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
            total = total + i;
            System.out.println("passenger  is given  notification call");
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this program is

```
passenger is waiting for the bus i am in synchronised method
wait ....  i am in synchronised method
passenger  is given  notification call
passenger  got notification
after 500500 time
```

and that means that when main thread printed "passenger is waiting for the bus i am in synchronised method" it was already in synchronized block and waiting. And the next statement printed is "wait ....  i am in synchronised method" which means that the passenger thread also went into its synchronized block. Remember, both synchronized blocks have the same object - `p` as the block object. This seems confusing as I understand that when main thread entered `synchronized(p)` block, the main thread must have blocked the object `p` and by definition no other thread can access or enter any synchronized block or method of object `p`!

Comment: What's the part you don't understand? This way we will attack that problem and not explain the whole program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can the main and passenger threads remain in a synchronized block at once?

`p.wait()` **releases** the lock on `p` until the thread re-awakens, so any number of threads can be `synchronized` on `p` as long as at most one is not waiting.

From [`Object`'s javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29):

> ```
> public final void wait() throws InterruptedException
> ```
>
> The current thread must own this object's monitor. **The thread releases ownership of this monitor** and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the `notify` method or the `notifyAll` method. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution.

Comment: @Mohitt, yw.  Happy waiting.